# adding custom role filter to wordpress woocommerce shop_manager

Tags: wordpress, function, user-roles, capability

Hello all i was wondering if someone could help me out. I would like to add a cap to the woocommerce shop manager role. I found this function but it will not work.

```
function add_capability() {
    // gets the author role
    $role = get_role( 'shop_manager' );

    // This only works, because it accesses the class instance.
    $role->add_cap( 'add_new_user' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_capability');
```

any one know of a solution i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the current list of capabilities, there's no capability called `add_new_user` . See the following link : http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities .

The correct capability to add is `create_users` , once the capability is added, the option appears under *Profile -> Add New User*

```
function add_capability() {
    // gets the author role
    $role = get_role( 'shop_manager' );

    // This only works, because it accesses the class instance.
    $role->add_cap( 'create_users' );    

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_capability');
```

Comment: Thank you very much Anand, i couldn't find the codex list of capabilities, but thanks to you I know where they are now.